# HTML navigation list shows multiple items as selected

Tags: html, navigation

[image]

I am working on a website, the navigation list of the website is in the picture. If I go to the page number 1, other pages are also shown as selected. But if I go to the page number 2 there is no problem.

Here is the code for navigation list. The list items shown as selected have different file names. How a list item now that it is selected ?

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php">
                <i class="ti-dashboard menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Ana Sayfa</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#kullanicilar" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="kullanicilar">
                <i class="ti-id-badge menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Kullanıcılar</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="kullanicilar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kullanicilari-listele.php">Kullanıcılar</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kullanici-olustur.php">Kullanıcı
                        Oluştur</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kullanici-istatistikleri-listele.php">Kullanıcı
                        İstatistikleri</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#workouts" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="workouts">
                <i class="ti-gallery menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Antrenmanlar</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="workouts">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="antrenmanlari-listele.php">Antrenmanlar</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="antrenman-olustur.php">Antrenman Oluştur</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="egzersizleri-listele.php">Tekil Egzersizler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tekil-egzersiz-olustur.php">Tekil</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#pilates" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="pilates">
                <i class="ti-timer menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Pilates</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="pilates">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pilates-egzersiz-setleri.php">Egzersiz Setleri</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pilates-egzersiz-seti-olustur.php">Egzersiz Seti Oluştur</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pilates-tekil-egzersizleri.php">Tekil Egzersizler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pilates-tekil-egzersiz-olustur.php">Tekil</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#yoga" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="yoga">
                <i class="ti-eye menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Yoga</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="yoga">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="yoga-egzersiz-setleri.php">Egzersiz Setleri</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="yoga-egzersiz-seti-olustur.php">Egzersiz Seti Oluştur</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="yoga-tekil-egzersizleri.php">Tekil Egzersizler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="yoga-tekil-egzersiz-olustur.php">Tekil Egzersiz Oluştur</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#streching" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="streching">
                <i class="ti-hand-open menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Streching</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="streching">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="streching-egzersiz-setleri.php">Egzersiz Setleri</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="streching-egzersiz-seti-olustur.php">Yeni Egzersiz Seti</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kstreching-tekil-egzersizleri.php">Tekil Egzersizler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="streching-tekil-egzersiz-olustur.php">Yeni Egzersiz</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sporKategorileri" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="sporKategorileri">
                <i class="ti-star menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Kategoriler</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="sporKategorileri">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kategorileri-listele.php">Kategoriler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="kategori-olustur.php">Yeni Kategori Oluştur</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#egzersizEkipmanlari" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="egzersizEkipmanlari">
                <i class="ti-basketball menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Egzersiz</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="egzersizEkipmanlari">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                                            href="egzersiz-ekipmanlari-listele.php">Ekipmanlar</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="egzersiz-ekipmani-olustur.php">Yeni Ekipman
                        Oluştur</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#vucutBolgeleri" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="vucutBolgeleri">
                <i class="ti-heart menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Vücut Bölgeleri</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="vucutBolgeleri">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                                            href="vucut-bolgeleri-listele.php">Vücut Bölgeleri</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="vucut-bolgesi-olustur.php">Vücut Bölgesi
                        Oluştur</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#urunler" aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="urunler">
                <i class="ti-package menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Ürünler</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="urunler">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="urunleri-listele.php">Ürünler</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="urun-olustur.php">Yeni Ürün Oluştur</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="urun-istatistikleri-listele.php">Ürün
                        İstatistikleri</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
'''
```

This is the page number 1

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
} else {
    include "veritabani/baglanti.php";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Online Gym Fitness Mobil Uygulama Yönetim Paneli</title>
    <!-- plugins:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/ti-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/base/vendor.bundle.base.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/repeater.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-scroller">
    <!-- partial:../../partials/_navbar.html -->
    <nav class="navbar col-lg-12 col-12 p-0 fixed-top d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="text-center navbar-brand-wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo mr-xl-5" href="../index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="mr-2"
                                                                                alt="logo"/></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo-mini" href="../index.php"><img src="../images/logo-mini.png" alt="logo"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="minimize">
                <span class="ti-view-list"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-right">
                <li class="nav-item nav-profile dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="profileDropdown">
                        <img src="../images/faces/user.png" alt="profile"/>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right navbar-dropdown" aria-labelledby="profileDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="veritabani/logout.php">
                            <i class="ti-power-off text-primary"></i>
                            Logout
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right d-lg-none align-self-center" type="button"
                    data-toggle="offcanvas">
                <span class="ti-view-list"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- partial -->
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
        <!-- partial:../partials/_sidebar.html -->
        <?php
        include "navbar.html";
        ?>
        <!-- partial -->
        <div class="main-panel">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 grid-margin">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Yeni Tekil Egzersiz</h4>
                                <p class="card-description">
                                    Yeni Tekil Egzersiz Oluşturma Formu
                                </p>
                                <form method="post" name="egzersizOlusturmaFormu" id="egzersizOlusturmaFormu"
                                      class="forms-sample">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizBasligi">Egzersiz Başlığı</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="egzersizBasligi"
                                               name="egzersizBasligi"
                                               required="required"
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizAltBaslik">Egzersiz Alt Başlık</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="egzersizAltBaslik"
                                               name="egzersizAltBaslik"
                                               required="required"
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizAciklama">Egzersiz Açıklama</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="egzersizAciklama"
                                               id="egzersizAciklama"
                                               required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizPremium">Premium içerik mi ?</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control"
                                                name="egzersizPremium" id="egzersizPremium">
                                            <option value="1">Evet</option>
                                            <option value="0">Hayır</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizVideoUrl">Video Embed Url</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                               name="egzersizVideoUrl" id="egzersizVideoUrl"
                                               required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizPopularite">Popülarite Skoru</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                               name="egzersizPopularite" id="egzersizPopularite">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizEkipmanKategorisi">Ekipman Kategorisi</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control" name="egzersizEkipmanKategorisi"
                                                id="egzersizEkipmanKategorisi">
                                            <?php
                                            $sorgu = "SELECT name,id FROM equipments ORDER BY name DESC";
                                            $sorguSonucu = mysqli_query($baglanti, $sorgu) or trigger_error("Hata: " . mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
                                            if ($sorguSonucu) {
                                                while ($equipment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorguSonucu)) {
                                                    echo "<option value='" . $equipment['id'] . "'>" . $equipment["name"] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizSporKategorisi">Kategori</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control" name="egzersizSporKategorisi"
                                                id="egzersizSporKategorisi">
                                            <?php
                                            $sorgu = "SELECT name,id FROM categories ORDER BY name DESC";
                                            $sorguSonucu = mysqli_query($baglanti, $sorgu) or trigger_error("Hata: " . mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
                                            if ($sorguSonucu) {
                                                while ($sport = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorguSonucu)) {
                                                    echo "<option value='" . $sport['id'] . "'>" . $sport['name'] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizVucutBolgesi">Vücut Bölgesi</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control" name="egzersizVucutBolgesi"
                                                id="egzersizVucutBolgesi">
                                            <?php
                                            $bodyPartsSql = "SELECT name,id FROM body_parts ORDER BY name DESC";
                                            $bodyParts = mysqli_query($baglanti, $bodyPartsSql) or trigger_error("Hata: " . mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
                                            if ($bodyParts) {
                                                while ($part = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bodyParts)) {
                                                    echo "<option value='" . $part['id'] . "'>" . $part['name'] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizZorlukDerecesi">Egzersiz Zorluk Derecesi</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control"
                                                name="egzersizZorlukDerecesi" id="egzersizZorlukDerecesi">
                                            <option value="1">Çok Kolay</option>
                                            <option value="2">Kolay</option>
                                            <option value="3">Orta</option>
                                            <option value="4">Zor</option>
                                            <option value="5">Çok Zor</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizOrtalamaSure">Egzersiz Ortalama Süresi (Dakika)</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control"
                                               name="egzersizOrtalamaSure" id="egzersizOrtalamaSure"
                                               required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="egzersizSetTipi">Setler Tekrarlı mı Süreli mi ?</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control"
                                                name="egzersizSetTipi" id="egzersizSetTipi">
                                            <option value="1">Tekrarlı</option>
                                            <option value="2">Süreli</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="repeater">
                                        <div class="repeater-heading" align="right">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary repeater-add-btn">Set Ekle
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="items" data-group="exercise_sets">
                                            <div class="item-content">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15px">
                                                        <label>Tekrar Sayısı/Süresi (Saniye) </label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                               required="required"
                                                               data-skip-name="true"
                                                               data-name="tekrarSayilari[]"
                                                        >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px">
                                                        <label>Dinlenme Süresi (Saniye)</label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                               required="required"
                                                               data-skip-name="true"
                                                               data-name="dinlenmeSureleri[]"
                                                        >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:30px;" align="center">
                                                        <button id="remove-btn"
                                                                onclick="$(this).parents('.items').remove()"
                                                                class="btn btn-danger">Sil
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Tanıtım Görseli Yükle</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="egzersizTanitimGorseli"
                                               id="egzersizTanitimGorseli"
                                               class="file-upload-default">
                                        <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control file-upload-info"
                                                   required="required"
                                                   disabled="">
                                            <span class="input-group-append">
                                              <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Görsel Seç</button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>

                                        <img id="gorsel_preview">
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">ONAYLA</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light">İPTAL</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- main-panel ends -->
</div>
<!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
<!-- container-scroller -->
<!-- plugins:js -->
<script src="../vendors/base/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="../js/off-canvas.js"></script>
<script src="../js/hoverable-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../js/template.js"></script>
<script src="../js/todolist.js"></script>
<script src="../js/file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="../js/repeater.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#egzersizOlusturmaFormu').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'veritabani/egzersiz-kayit.php', // Verileri Post Ettiğimiz dosya adı
            type: 'POST', // Form Metodumuz
            data: new FormData(this), // Form ile gelen verilerimiz
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // Form Post edildikten sonra yapılacak işlem
                //  $('#result').html('<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%;"><span class="sr-only">Lütfen Bekleyiniz....</span></div></div>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // veritabani/etkinlik-ekle.php dosyamıza verilerin gönderildikten sonra işlem başarılı ise upload.php ile gelen sonuç değerini yazdıracağımız satır
                alert(data);
                $('#egzersizOlusturmaFormu')[0].reset(); // İşlem başarılı olduktan sonra formu sıfırlar
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#gorsel_preview').attr('src', e.target.result).attr('style', 'margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 25px; height: 150px; width: 150px');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#egzersizTanitimGorseli").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#repeater').createRepeater();
    });
</script>
<!-- endinject -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not clear your problem is coming from the code you've displayed.  Provide complete example

Comment: I added the code I have displayed